# External RSS images are very blurry

Tags: rss, simplepie

I have a site and I'm using Simple Pie to bring in external rss feeds. I'm displaying images, but they are showing up very blurry. When I click through to the story, they look fine on the original site. Why are they showing up blurry on my site?

Here's my site: http://leadgenixhosting.com/~freepub/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason these images are "blurry" is because they're much smaller than the size you're scaling them to. Without seeing the feeds you're using, there's no way of knowing if that can be fixed, but my suspicion is that only the thumbnail images are included in the feed.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspect too.